# How to manually use a protractor ExpectedCondition?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, expected-condition

I'm new to protractor and I want to create an expect like this:

`expect(elementIsVisible).toBe(true);`

I saw that protractor has [EC (expected conditions)](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions), namely `EC.visibilityOf` which seems to be what I'm looking for. However, I'm not entirely sure what `visibilityOf` returns.

I find [the docs](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf) very obscure:

```
RETURNS
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Type    |                                        Description                                        |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| !function | An expected condition that returns a promise representing whether the element is visible. |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What it returns? A `Promise` or an *expected condition*?

Well, considering that chaining a `.then` triggers `then is not a function`, it seems it returns an *expected condition*. But what's that?

In all Protractor documentation examples, this return value is used in `browser.wait` functions.

I don't want to use it like that, I want to have a `true`/`false` value in my `expect` condition.

If I try to find more information from Selenium's examples, Protractor (a javascript implementation) redirects to [Java documentation](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)...

Comment: And why can't you use `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(xxx), 5000); expect(xxx.isDisplayed()).toBe(true)` where `EC` is `var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;`?

Comment: `xxx.isDisplayed()` will do. Based on the docs, it is not clear that `EC.visibilityOf(xxx)` can exclusively be used in a `wait` or equivalent API method. So one cannot use it manually? Or is too hacky and not worth it?

Comment: You can look at the source code for [visiblityof](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/d74356b809feb0f1342d42622247e233860e30d3/lib/expectedConditions.ts#L393). It basically returns `elementFinder.isDisplayed().then(passBoolean, falseIfMissing);`, so you can play with this, but either way you will have to wait for the control to be visible, so I don't see a reason to overcomplicate this. `visibilityof` cannot wait in itself, it need a function `browser.wait` to wait, so you need this anyway.

Comment: ok, seems that answers the question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visibilityOf` and all other ExpectedConditions return functions. You can call this function, and you will get `Promise<boolean>` . Basically all ExpectedConditions are predicates - functions, that when called return promise resolved to boolean (should be no exceptions thrown). So basically you can try to use something like this:

```
let shouldBeVisible = protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf
expect(
    shouldBeVisible($('div.button'))() // Notice () - this where we are manually calling predicate function to get boolean result
).toBeTruthy('Element div.button should be visible');
```

But lucky you - if you are using JasmineJS - you can try my lib to assert visibility of elements:
https://github.com/Xotabu4/jasmine-protractor-matchers

So you will get not just checking element visibility, but matcher will automatically wait for a while to element to become visible. Check this:

`expect($('div.button')).toAppear()`

More examples in README.MD